Visual Studio 2010 Windows SDK override with latest version
There's default macro with $(WindowsSdkDir) used by Visual Studio. This is Microsoft SDKs with version 7.0A.
I want to use new Window 11 SDK with new API, how can I override $(WindowsSdkDir) in preference of latest includes and libraries folder?
Changes at registry directory at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows not seems to work, because the directory structure is different after all these years.

I doubt vs2010 would support it

tried, but not able to build. The folder structure changed. If possible probably not straight forward anyway.
